# Questions on Proofs - Equivalent Conditions of Normal Subgroup - Fraleigh p. 141 Theorem 14.13

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, intuition, normal-subgroups

> [image]
>
> <s>(1.) Why did Fraleigh shirk the proof for $(2) \implies (1)$?</s>
>   By dint of Arthur's comment, $(2) \iff \color{crimson}{gHg^{-1} \subseteq H} \quad \wedge \quad gHg^{-1} \supseteq H \implies \color{crimson}{gHg^{-1} \subseteq H} \iff (1)$

(2.) In $(1) \implies (2)$, how does $\{ghg^{-1} : h \in H \} \subseteq H$?

(3.) I know left cosets $\neq$ right cosets. The same $H$ appears on both sides $gH = Hg$ in:
 $gH = Hg \iff gh_1 = h_2g$, hence why isn't $h_1 = h_2$ always?
[I read](http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/lecture9ws.pdf) $gH = Hg$ is a set equality and not an equality elementwise. But I'm confounded.

To boot, I know $gh_1 = h_2g \iff G$ Abelian $\iff \color{magenta}{g^{-1}}gh_1 = \color{magenta}{g^{-1}}gh_2 \iff h_1 = h_2$.
$G$ can be nonAbelian hence if it is nonabelian, the previous line muffs.

Comment: Are you trying to construct a Solutions Manual to Fraleigh's book? So many questions....

Comment: (1): Because it is trivial. (2): That is precisely the assumption (this actually also answers (4)).

Comment: (1) says that $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$. (2) implies this trivially.

Comment: (3) Why **would** anyone think $gh_1=h_2g$ implies $h_1=h_2$? Examine your assumptions and prejudices; in the noncommutative world we can't cancel something on the left with something elsewhere on the right. (3) Rewriting $gH=Hg$ yields $gHg^{-1}=H$, and (ostensibly) weakening this yields $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$. Sometimes "moves" in math are like "moves" in chess: you have to learn how to see multiple steps ahead, like in this case where you need to see two steps ahead. (For example, one can solve $2x+1=0$ immediately mentally by seeing two steps ahead, "intuition" or not.)

Comment: @Arthur Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you understand what I was saying about point (3)? It doesn't make sense to ask why X isn't the case, when there is no reason  to believe X in the first place.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to believe $h_1g=gh_2\Rightarrow h_1=h_2$. In fact, this is clearly equivalent to believing that $g$ commutes with everything in $H$, and if you believe that for any $g$ and $H$, you believe all groups are abelian. Do you seriously remain perplexed about how groups can be nonabelian? Is it strange that there can be things that don't commute with each other? **Why** do you need convincing that the one thing doesn't imply the other in the first place, if you have no basis to believe otherwise, and counterexamples can be made up on the spot with ease?

Comment: @anon Thanks a lot again. I understand groups can be nonabelian. I'm not perplexed about this. But because $H$ is the same in $gH = Hg$, for some reason I just feel this $\implies gh_1 = h_2g$ for $h_1 = h_2$, again because the same $H$ is on both sides of the equation. What did I bungle?

Comment: You are asking me about your feelings? I have no idea. Other than my guess that you are prejudiced by your abelian preconceptions, or somesuch. Just because conjugation by $g$ fixes $H$ setwise does not mean it fixes $H$ *pointwise*: it can move things around inside $H$, without anything spilling out, and that's all that $gH=Hg$ means.

Comment: @anon What does "anything spiling out" mean? I want to figure out the bungle hence how would commutativity induce any prejudice? Are you saying that my muff is because I think $gh_1 = h_2g \iff G$ Abelian $\iff \color{magenta}{g^{-1}}gh_1 = \color{magenta}{g^{-1}}gh_2 \iff h_1 = h_2$.

Comment: Maybe you need to see an example where $gH=Hg$ and $gh_1=h_2g$ but $h_1\ne h_2$. It's easy to do. Take $G$ to be the symmetric group on 3 letters, and $H$ to be the three-element subgroup. Or, take $G$ to be the group of symmetries of the square, and $H$ to be the group generated by rotation halfway around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_g:G\mapsto G$ defined by $f_g(x)=gxg{-1}$. Note that $f_g$ is an bijection from $G$ to $G$(actually it is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$) Thus,restriction of $f_g$ on any subset $S$ of $G$ is also a bijection from $S$ to its image.

Now,if $G$ is finite your question is very trivial since if $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ then we know that $|gNg^{-1}|=|N|\implies gNg^{-1}=N $.(their order equal since it is an bijection)

For general case,Since $f_g$ is bijection so it has inverse namely $f_{g^{-1}} $ or vice versa.Thus,restriction of $f_g$ on a subset $S$,$f_g:S\mapsto Im(S)$ is invertable.

Now, it is given that $f_g(N)\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$.So,

$$f_{g^{-1}}(N)\subseteq N$$
$$f_g(f_{g^{-1}}(N))\subseteq f_g(N)$$
$$N\subseteq f_g(N)\implies N=f_g(N)$$ Which is showing that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N\implies gNg^{-1}=N$ we are done.

Comment: Apologies, but how does this answer my questions?

Comment: @FrankMuer:
 You edited your question $6$ hours ago and my answer was given almost one moth ago. (I do not even remember previous version of the question). When I have time I will try to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But my previous questions weren't about proofs.

Answer (score 1):

2) We have to prove that if $ghg^{-1}\in H$ for each $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ then $\{ghg^{-1}:h\in H\}\subseteq H$ for each $g\in G$.

Take $x\in \{ghg^{-1}:h\in H\}$. We must prove $x \in H$. $x\in \{ghg^{-1}:h\in H\}$ means there exists $h\in H$ such that $x=ghg^{-1}$. By assumption $ghg^{-1}\in H$, thus $x\in H$.

3) Equality $gH=Hg$ means $\{gh:h\in H\}=\{hg:h\in H\}$.
In other words, for each $h\in H$ there exists $h^\prime\in H$ such that $gh=h^\prime g$, but, in general, we have $h\neq h^\prime$. On the other hand, if $G$ is abelian, then you have $h=h^\prime$.

4) If $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for each $g\in G$ then also $g^{-1}Hg=g^{-1}H(g^{-1})^{-1}\subseteq H$ thus you obtain $H\subseteq gHg^{-1}$.

5) The equivalence of the following stataments:

1. $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for each $g\in G$;
2. $gHg^{-1}=H$ for each $g\in G$;

follows from the presence of the *for all* $g\in G$. Without this *for all* $g\in G$ the equivalence will be no longer true.

Comment: I deleted the redundant X. Please notify if my edit's bungled.